# Compare content of one text file with the other text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I Want to compare the content of one text files with content of other text file, if it is not there it should create a separate file of the non matched content. how can we do this using batch script.?

Comment: fc or comp. Type `fc/?` or `comp/?`

Comment: But if the word is not there, how to create a different files of that non matched word.??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what to search where, but this can be used as a start

```
findstr /l /x /v /g:file.a file.b > file.c
findstr /l /x /v /g:file.b file.a >> file.c
```

The first line will search `file.b` for the lines not contained in `file.a` and send the output to `file.c`

The next line  will search `file.a` for the lines not contained in `file.b` and append the output to `file.c`

At the end `file.c` will contain all the non common lines between `file.a` and `file.b`

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
findstr /vlx /g:b.txt a.txt > c.txt
```

Comment: Hi MC, thanks for the response, now what i want is, lets say we have two files, A.txt & B.txt, A.txt contains words lets say Ankit, MC, Ank and B.txt contains words Ankit, ND, Anki (Please note all the names are there in new lines in both the files), now ous script should take the first word from A.txt and compare it with all the words in B.txt, if the word is there then ok if it is not there it should copy that word into other txt file lets say C.txt. Hope this will help you understand what is my requirement.

Comment: Hi MC, its throwing error saying that cannot read strings from B.txt

Comment: @AnkitGupta, is there anything inside the files?

Comment: Only names that needs to be compared are there in the text files.

Comment: @AnkitGupta, the usual reasons for the error you see can be: the file does not exist (or wrong path), the file has no content or the file can not be readed (maybe it is locked or has a not usual encoding)